# Android Canvas DRAWTEXT POSITION CRAZY

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawtext

I am here for hours trying to do a Simple text to be on the first line my
canvas and position RIGHT

I have a preview with my camera, and I would like to add some information on the top + right

I have tried a lot of code but no one that works!

I can not understand WHY x and y, for example, can not simple be 0 and draw the text to the begin canvas...

Can someone help me with it?

I have canvas and I need to drawtext to TOP -> right side.
The text will be like this "So far, move to close"

It is the code that I am using now, It works but the position message is 
Center screen in both horizontal and vertical.

It can be centered but I would like it on the TOP.

```
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    paint.setTextSize(150);

    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds("a", 0, 1, bounds);

    canvas.drawText(cText, canvas.getWidth() >> 1, (canvas.getHeight() + bounds.height()) >> 1, paint);
```

Note:
I can not understand the logic for this position X and Y here.
I have checked a lot of examples but I still without understanding.

Without to say that if I move the device horizontal and vertical sometimes the position is different or not visible.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post the code you've already tried.  You're more likely to get help if you do.  :)

Comment: Added my code. thanks